# Fast interprocess communication in C# (for Windows X86-64)

Tags: c#, c++, ipc

Yet another question from C++ guy digging under C#.

This time its inter-process communication.
So in C++ you can use [boost interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)'s memory mapped files for instance and it will end up being fast and robust.

C# gives [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications?redirectedfrom=MSDN) options. I want to know which one is the fastest. For instances I dig a little into [File mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications?redirectedfrom=MSDN#using-a-file-mapping-for-ipc) and apparently it only gives you a higher level interaction over the memory region through MemporyMappedViewAccessor. So I have 2 questions.

1. Is there a way to create a mapped region using File Mapping then get a byte* or void* to that memory and directly read/write? (Which I only assume will be faster than MemporyMappedViewAccessor. Pretty much what boost IPC lets you do)
2. If the answer to #1 is no, which one from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications?redirectedfrom=MSDN) list will be faster? (Assuming single producer and single consumer processes)

Comment: It depends on the platform

Comment: @DanielA.White edited the question

Comment: Pipes are very fast

Comment: To get a pointer to a `MemoryMappedViewAccessor`, you have to go through its `SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle` and use `AcquirePointer`/`ReleasePointer`.

Answer (score -1):

[MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) is what is used on Windows to create shared memory.

You can look at [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory) for some details.

Comment: That's a C++ function. To use it in C#, you have to use P/Invoke, but then you should really use the `MemoryMappedFile` class instead, it's much easier.

Comment: True, but tags said "C#" and "C++"... So... :)

Comment: @eti Accessing the Windows API from C# is a [solved problem](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32).